# Cleaning the lint or is it insulation from my gas dryer

Tags: insulation, cleaning, dryer

I'm wanting to clean the lint out of my clothes dryer, I bought an attachment for the main area and hose but I see what I think must be lint inside the back panel as well, if I remove the panel what kind of problems will I get in to? The material looks and smells like it's been scorched too, so I am kind of worried about what problems I'm going to run into. By the way the dryer is gas.
Thank you for the info/help in advance,

Comment: There shouldn't be lint randomly lying on the back cover of the dryer but please send us a photo. Typically lint is collectively grey more times than not, and it isnt glued to anything, it just pulls right off.

Comment: We really need a photo to help, sometimes materials in the insulation get scorched when the ductwork gets plugged so a photo would be helpful. Most of the exterior back panels on dryers I have worked on are painted sheet metal.